# Unable to add Siri capability in Xcode and apple developer centre too

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sirikit

I did a lot of research but didn't got any help. I am unable to add capability of 'Siri' in xcode and can't see any option in my apple developer account too, I am asked to purchase the membership instead. By any chance is it possible to create an app in iTunesConnect without making the payment of USD99. I just want to learn some new stuffs like Siri integration, but to do so I need to add the capability in app from developer account and to add an app I have to get enrolled and pay $99. 
Even for learning purpose payment is required?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Apple docs mentioned, you can use your free apple account to access certain app capabilities. Refer the below link for the supported capabilities for free.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH38-SW1

For remaining capabilities, you need to have developer account membership paying USD 99.

Comment: Ohk. I found this link now https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/
But I wonder why 'Siri' is not at all listed. Could you please tell me if you know, or should I ask another question for it?

Comment: Since Apple didn't include SiriKit in free account supported capabilities, it should require apple membership to use.

Comment: Yes I got that but it hasn't been enlisted at all. The list shows all the capabilities which are available and have been marked with whether it could be used with free/membership account. But no siri in it.

Answer (score 0):

you need 1 paying member on a team to use iTunes connect. But as it is only a distribution platform, I dont see why you need it.

NOTHING needs iTunes connect account (exception being store kit IIRC)

check https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle and whatever entitlements you can give there, work

Comment: I wanted to add capability of siri in my app for learning purpose.

Comment: what has that to do with needing iTunes though? capabilities are enabled via https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

Comment: when I clicked on the link which you entered here, a message is being shown to me "Purchase your membership" I don't think capabilities could be enabled from developer centre without making the payment [Thats what my question is]

Comment: if you cant go that link and you can u do it locally in xcode?

Comment: no even in Xcode also I am unable to add this capability. In capability tab I get Maps, background modes, inter-app audio, keychain sharing, app groups, data protection, homeKit, healthKit, wireless accessory config, as said by Basheer in his answer these capabilities are available for free.

Comment: ok so that is your answer ;) reformulate the question and accept basheer then. this answer that you dont ever need to use iTunesConnect

Answer (score 0):

1. You should enable it in apple's developer portal.
2. Go to "Identifiers" and select your App.
3. Scroll and check SiriKit and Save it.
4. Then you will have to create a new Provisioning Profile with the identifier.